# Approximate function by stacking building blocks

Tags: approximation, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, quadratic-programming

I need some help with a 'generalised Lego problem':

Given a **function $f(x)\geq 0$** on an **interval $[a,b]$**, and a **'building block' function $p(x)\geq 0$ with compact support**. The maximum of f shall be larger than the maximum of p. Think of $[a,b]=[-5, 5]$ and the support of $p$ shall be $[-.2, .2]$.

**My goal is to approximate $f$ by stacking translations of $p$** (i.e. local copies of the form $p(x-x^{\ast})$ for given grid points $x^{\ast}$).

My approach so far: Given a **grid $\{x_i\}_{i=1,\dots,n}$**, I am looking for **non-negative integer coefficients $\{a_i\}_{i=1,\dots,n}$**, such that the following is **minimal**:
$$
\|f-\sum_{i}a_i \,p(\cdot-x_i)\|_{L^2}^2 := \int_a^b \left|f(x)-\sum_{i}a_ip(x-x_i)\right|^2\,dx\;.
$$

It is straightforward to reformulate this problem as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\cdot \mathbf{a}^\top\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b}^{\top}\mathbf{a} \to \min\;,
$$
with a symmetric matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ and a vector $\mathbf{b}$.

(Up to constant factors, $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{f}$ have entries $\left(p(\cdot-x_i), p(\cdot-x_j\right)_{L^2}$ and $\left(p(\cdot-x_i), f\right)_{L^2}$, respectively. )

I am aware that if the coefficients were to be allowed to be arbitrarily real, this is standard. **How do I tackle this problem *with integer and non-negative solutions* without having to buy a huge and expensive black-box optimisation software?** Or am I following the wrong approach at all? Would it be even possible to optimise for the grid as well?

Comment: What about using a free/open-source solver?

Comment: Open for suggestions. Octave has one in principle, but it is buggy and does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of open-source solvers available from [COIN-OR](https://www.coin-or.org/projects/). I'm not a MATLAB user, but a quick search turned up the [OPTI Toolbox](https://www.inverseproblem.co.nz/OPTI/index.php) for MATLAB, which includes several of the COIN-OR projects.